# Adjusting aperture, ISO and shutter speed manually? Huawei P9

Tags: camera, huawei

I have a Huawei P9. The dual camera is good. The camera software (app) is also good and offers control over the hardware that most stock camera apps don't. BUT, in the pro mode, to control the exposure of a shot, I can manually play with the ISO and the shutter speed but not the aperture :S *I don't know if I'm missing something here.*

#### In brief, my question is:

- How can I manually adjust the ISO, the shutter speed and the aperture for a single shot on my Huawei P9 whether using the camera app it offers or using a third party camera app?
- OR, how to adjust aperture in pro mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to standalone digital cameras, most smartphones have a fixed aperture due to concerns such as device thickness. [P9 is no exception](http://techprolonged.com/2016/05/huawei-p9-camera-aperture-effect-bokeh-mode-how-to/), and is equipped with a f/2.2 fixed aperture lens. Under the "DoF control" mode in the stock camera app, different apertures are *simulated* using the data captured simultaneously from two camera sensors.

Since it's not a hardware implementation of aperture, it's unlikely any 3rd-party software will be able to make use of it (proprietary algorithm). As of now, unless Huawei themselves decide to add such feature to the stock camera through an update later, you're out of luck.

Comment: Additional speculation: the second camera sensor, being a black-and-white one, might not allow for sophisticated controls such as ISO and shutter speed. Imagine you were to shoot in Pro mode with aperture simulation available, but then the ISO and shutter speed tweaks are only applied upon the data of the main sensor - in this case I don't think the simulation algorithm is supposed to work properly at all. This is probably why it's not included at this stage, and probably never will.